# Ubuntu packages: gazebo vs gz-harmonic

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I have installed ROS2 humble + Gazebo harmonic for playing with Ardupilot.

Now I want to follow several tutorials to make myself more familiar with ROS2.

One asks me to install packages like `ros-humble-gazebo-*` which leads to installing `gazebo`.

In the package manager I see this `gz-harmonic` is installed:
[image]

I doubt that installing `gazebo` could break `gz-harmonic` installation. Am I right? Could you please point to the explanation of how packages are related to each other? Could they be deprecated by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to read the official Gazebo installation instruction [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu).

It basically says that `gz-garden` and `gazebo-classic` (what you called gazebo) cannot coexist on the same machine. So you may want to uninstall `gz-harmonic` if you want to follow some `gazebo-classic` tutorials.

**Warning**
Anyway, notice that if you install the `ros-humble-gz-*` stuff, you are installing the packages for `gz-fortress`, which may lead to unexpected behaviors due to compatibility issues between versions. You may want to install those packages from sources by looking the official repository of the package.